# QuickSearchBox not showing any search results for my app

Tags: android, android-searchmanager, android-search

I have enabled/checked my app in the settings for QSB.  It displays suggestions correctly in the SeachView in my activity.  I added android:includeInGlobalSearch="true" but still do not see any results.  Are there any other things I might have forgotten?

Here is my searchable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="android.myapp.searchsuggestions"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/settings_description"
    android:includeInGlobalSearch="true" />
```

EDIT: Okay, I have noticed that it is working in QSB in Froyo but not in 4.2 and 4.3.  Just weird.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
In my provider tag in my manifest, I had set exported="false"
This, of course, prevents the provider's data from being seen outside of my application.  So, I set it to "true" and it works now.

```
<provider android:name=".SearchSuggestionsProvider" android:exported="true"
        android:authorities="com.example.myapp.searchsuggestions"/>
```

Comment: No idea why it was working on Froyo even when exported="false"  Maybe a bug in Froyo.